# form from front-end not receiving properly on req.body on backend nodejs

Tags: http, express, fetch, body-parser, mern

I'm using body parser and react for my front end.
I'm trying to create a user; below is the front end side of fetching the data from the back end server:

```
registering (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let form = e.target
  let name = form.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value

  fetch('http://localhost:5000/createacc', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({name: name})
  })
```

below is the backend receiving portion:

```
function create (req, res, next) {
  console.log('req is ...', req.body)
}
```

currently the console log is this:

```
req is ... { '{"name":"Smiley"}': '' }
```

I won't be able to properly use the information like this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are partially correct, you have received a string that needs to be parsed.  There is no need to use JSON.stringify() when sending a request. 
 Also, by sending an object you should use content type application/json.  Its possible you have forgotten to include body parser middleware as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Content-Type` and `body` is inconsistent. The `Content-Type` says the content is `x-www-form-urlencoded` but the body format is JSON.

If you want to keep `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the body format should like `a=xxx&b=yyy`. For your code, it would be:

```
body: 'name='+name
```

If you want to transfer the data as JSON, the `Content-Type` should be changed to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I would like to share

1. The data that you are sending in a json data, so put this in the headers

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

2. 

FrontEnd:

If you are planning to deal with more complex formData or uploading files then the best option is to use FormData. You have to change few things for that.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', name)
...
other things that you might want to add
...
```

Now the that data that will be sent is type 'multipart/form-data'. Probably you might not need to explicitly mention that is the frontend but It case of an issue you might try adding that.

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

BackEnd:

If you are using node as a backend end framework then we might use multer to parse the formData.

add this on top.
`upload.none()` is used when you don't have any image or file that you want to upload.
you can use `upload.single('name_of_that_field')` to upload somethings and then get access to that from req.file. you can upload multiple things also. Check documentation or other answers on this topic to get a clearer picture

```
// install multer first
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/your-route', upload.none(), other middlewares, (req, res) => {
  // Now you can access your formData from req.body
  // req.body.name for this example will return the name you sent
});
```